# SQLite: Summary data of a query result

Tags: sqlite

I have the following query that provides me with the 10 most recent records in the database:

```
SELECT
    dpDate AS Date,
    dpOpen AS Open,
    dpHigh AS High,
    dpLow AS Low,
    dpClose AS Close
FROM DailyPrices 
WHERE dpTicker = 'DL.AS'
ORDER BY dpDate DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The result of this query is as follows:

```
bash-3.2$ sqlite3 myData < Queries/dailyprice.sql
Date        Open        High        Low         Close     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
2016-06-13  4.0         4.009       3.885       3.933     
2016-06-10  4.23        4.236       4.05        4.08      
2016-06-09  4.375       4.43        4.221       4.231     
2016-06-08  4.406       4.474       4.322       4.35      
2016-06-07  4.377       4.466       4.369       4.384     
2016-06-06  4.327       4.437       4.321       4.353     
2016-06-03  4.34        4.428       4.316       4.335     
2016-06-02  4.434       4.51        4.403       4.446     
2016-06-01  4.51        4.512       4.317       4.399     
2016-05-31  4.613       4.67        4.502       4.526     
bash-3.2$
```

Whilst I need to plot the extracted data, I also need to obtain the following summary data of the dataset:

1. Minimum date ==> 2016-05-31
2. Maximum date ==> 2016-06-13
3. Open value at minimum date ==> 4.613
4. Close value at maximum date ==> 3.933
5. Maximum of High column ==> 4.67
6. Minimum of Low column ==> 3.885

How can I, as newbie, approach this issue?    Can this be done in one query?

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Best regards,

GAM

Comment: directly with query might be very tricky. is there any limitation to use pl/sql or any other language to parse it

Comment: Dear DevD, I use Perl to read the data into an array.  Subsequently, I could use Perl to obtain the wanted values.  However, I trying to explore SQLite ways of obtaining the data -- I want to climb up the SQLite learning curve.  As a newbie, I have been exploring avenues of a query on a query result -- but without success on this issue.  BR GAM

Comment: A single query returns a 'table' with a fixed number of columns, and a certain number of rows. Please show how the desired output of your query should look like.

Comment: The desired output should be as follows:

Comment: minDate maxDate Open High Low Close

Comment: 2016-05-31 2016-06-13 4.613 3.933 4.67 3.885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired output can be achieved with

- aggregate functions on a convenient common table expression,
  which uses OPs expression verbatim
- OPs method, with `limit 1` applied to common table expression,
  for getting mindate and maxdate among the ten days

Query:

```
WITH Ten(Date,Open,High,Low,Close) AS 
(SELECT dpDate  AS Date,
        dpOpen  AS Open,
        dpHigh  AS High,
        dpLow   AS Low,
        dpClose AS Close
 FROM DailyPrices
 WHERE dpTicker = 'DL.AS'
 ORDER BY dpDate DESC LIMIT 10)

SELECT min(Date) AS mindate,
       max(Date) AS maxdate,
       (SELECT Open  FROM Ten ORDER BY Date ASC  LIMIT 1) AS Open,
       max(High) AS High,
       min(Low)  AS Low,
       (SELECT Close FROM Ten ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1) AS Close
FROM Ten;
```

Output (`.headers on` and `.mode column`):

```
mindate     maxdate     Open        High        Low         Close
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
2016-05-31  2016-06-13  4.613       4.67        3.885       3.933
```

Note:
I think the order of values in OPs last comment do not match the order of columns in the preceding comment by OP.
I chose the order from the preceding comment.
The  order in the last comment seems to me to be "mindate, maxdate, Open, Close, High, Low".
Adapting my proposed query to that order would be simple.

Using SQLite 3.18.0 2017-03-28 18:48:43

Here is the `.dump` of my toy database, i.e. my MCVE, in case something is unclear. (I did not enter the many decimal places, it is probably a float rounding thing.)

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE dailyPrices (dpDate date, dpOpen float, dpHigh float, dpLow float, dpClose float, dpTicker varchar(10));
INSERT INTO dailyPrices(dpDate,dpOpen,dpHigh,dpLow,dpClose,dpTicker) VALUES('2016-06-13',4.0,4.009000000000000341,3.8849999999999997868,3.9329999999999998294,'DL.AS');
INSERT INTO dailyPrices(dpDate,dpOpen,dpHigh,dpLow,dpClose,dpTicker) VALUES('2016-06-10',4.2300000000000004263,4.2359999999999997655,4.0499999999999998223,4.080000000000000071,'DL.AS');
INSERT INTO dailyPrices(dpDate,dpOpen,dpHigh,dpLow,dpClose,dpTicker) VALUES('2016-06-09',4.375,4.4299999999999997157,4.2210000000000000852,4.2309999999999998721,'DL.AS');
INSERT INTO dailyPrices(dpDate,dpOpen,dpHigh,dpLow,dpClose,dpTicker) VALUES('2016-06-08',4.4059999999999996944,4.4740000000000001989,4.3220000000000000639,4.3499999999999996447,'DL.AS');
INSERT INTO dailyPrices(dpDate,dpOpen,dpHigh,dpLow,dpClose,dpTicker) VALUES('2016-06-07',4.3769999999999997797,4.4660000000000001918,4.3689999999999997726,4.384000000000000341,'DL.AS');
INSERT INTO dailyPrices(dpDate,dpOpen,dpHigh,dpLow,dpClose,dpTicker) VALUES('2016-06-06',4.3269999999999999573,4.4370000000000002771,4.3209999999999997299,4.3529999999999997584,'DL.AS');
INSERT INTO dailyPrices(dpDate,dpOpen,dpHigh,dpLow,dpClose,dpTicker) VALUES('2016-06-03',4.3399999999999998578,4.4370000000000002771,4.3209999999999997299,4.3529999999999997584,'DL.AS');
INSERT INTO dailyPrices(dpDate,dpOpen,dpHigh,dpLow,dpClose,dpTicker) VALUES('2016-06-02',4.4340000000000001634,4.5099999999999997868,4.4029999999999995807,4.4459999999999997299,'DL.AS');
INSERT INTO dailyPrices(dpDate,dpOpen,dpHigh,dpLow,dpClose,dpTicker) VALUES('2016-06-01',4.5099999999999997868,4.5119999999999995665,4.3170000000000001705,4.3990000000000000213,'DL.AS');
INSERT INTO dailyPrices(dpDate,dpOpen,dpHigh,dpLow,dpClose,dpTicker) VALUES('2016-05-31',4.6130000000000004334,4.6699999999999999289,4.5019999999999997797,4.525999999999999801,'DL.AS');
COMMIT;
```